# SystemTray based application without window on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, awt, trayicon

How do I do an application that runs only as a SystemTray TrayIcon on mac os x, (without an awt window and dock icon)?

The code I'm using is this:

```
public class App
{   
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    final TrayIcon trayIcon;

    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tray.gif");

        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");

        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);


        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("Tray is not supported");
        //  System Tray is not supported

    }
}
}
```

The problem is I'm getting a dock icon with title com.cc.ew.App

Comment: And what is your question? What's wrong?

Comment: I have the trayicon and a java app on the dock, instead of just the trayicon. I will edit the question and clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent icon in dock, you must in `<your-app>-Info.plist` file add boolean key   [`LSUIElement`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) and set it to YES.

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is standard macos convention. All apps do the same.